# ng-repeat list doesn't update immediately after api call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-drive-api, angularjs-ng-repeat

My web app view lists folders and their children in a nested list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="folderLi" ng-repeat="folder in folders">
    <a href="" ng-click="listFolderFiles( folder )">{{folder.title}}</a>
    <ul >
      <li ng-repeat="child in folder.children">
          {{child.title}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I load the initial list of folders, the list updates immediately to display the folders. However, there is no children object on each folder at that point. That is filled out when the folder is clicked and the app calls the Google Drive API to retrieve the folder's children. The controller includes this function:

```
$scope.listFolderFiles = function( folder ) {
  var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v2/files',
    'method': 'GET',
    'params' : {
        'q' : "'" + folder.id + "' in parents"
      }
  });


request.then(function(response){
     //log successful response
     console.log(response);
     folder.children = response.result.items;
           }, function(response) {
     //log error
      console.log(response);
   })
  }
```

This function correctly retrieves the information and updates the model. However, the ng-repeat list of children is not updated and displayed immediately. Instead, it is updated and displayed the next time a folder is clicked. It seems like this function is updating the view before the api call is finished, so the next time the function runs the view gets updated to show the last API call's response. Thoughts?

Comment: try to force digest  cycle by using `$scope.$apply();`

Comment: Can't you add folder as a $scope var ? It could force angular to track it.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngGAPI 
It's an Angular based library to do Google Drive the AngularJS way. Currently early alpha, but is prob stable enough for you to use. All of the code in your question would be replaced by a single line folder.children =   DriveService.files.list({q:"'" + folder.id + "' in parents"},true).data . Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: btw, note that the code you've pasted will also return trashed files. This might be deliberate, but it is more usual to see "trashed=false" within the q property.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question about how to stop getting the trashed files...before I even asked that question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update outside angular's knowledge. So your view is not updated. You need to use `$scope.$apply()` or `$timeout` to run a digest cycle.

```
request.then(function(response){
     //log successful response
     console.log(response);
     //folder.children = response.result.items; //Required in case of $scope.$apply()
     $timeout(function(){folder.children = response.result.items;}); //Or $scope.$apply(); (Don't forget to inject $timeout in your controller)
           }, function(response) {
     //log error
      console.log(response);
   })
  }
```

Comment: You are correct Zee, but, using $apply directly is not a good practice in my opinion. I'd rather suggest to wrap the content into a $timeout(function(){},0);

Comment: @aorfevre. Yes you are right, i forgot abt that. :) I also prefer `$timeout`. Don't know how i missed. Updated. :)

Comment: Even `$timeout` is not good practice. Use `$q` to wrap the external promise. `$q` will internally trigger the digest-cycle.

Comment: @Yoshi. Just out of curiosity, why not `$timeout`?

Comment: @Zee because it feels dirty ;) No really, I simply think that `$timeout` is not really meant to be used for this, it's just an implementation detail that it will have the desired effect on the application.

Comment: I'm with Yoshi. This is precisely what $q is for